# What's the reason behind this access restriction for superclass and subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I'm trying to understand the rationale for the last statement of my code being illegal in Java. See comment below.

```
public class Rectangle {

private int height;
private int width;

public Rectangle(int height, int width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

}
```

---

```
class ColoredRectangle extends Rectangle {
private String color;

public ColoredRectangle(int height, int width, String color) {
    super(height, width);
    this.color = color;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ColoredRectangle blueRectangle = new ColoredRectangle(2, 4, "blue");
    Rectangle sameObjectDifferentType = blueRectangle;
    ((ColoredRectangle) sameObjectDifferentType).getColor(); //Will compile
    sameObjectDifferentType.getColor();  //Won't compile 
  }
}
```

I know that I shouldn't use this design, and instead use different constructors. I know that `getColor()` is "not defined in Rectangle." Still, the way I think about this code is: sameObjectDifferentType is a reference to an object that is both a Rectangle and a ColoredRectangle, and therefore I should be able to access all of its members regardless if I declare the reference as Rectangle or ColoredRectangle. So... why is Java designed like this?

Comment: `color = this.color` should be `this.color = color`.

Comment: *I know that getColor() is "not defined in Rectangle."* That is precisely correct. `getColor()` is not defined in `Rectangle`. You thought about it correctly the first time.

Comment: What happens if you have an other class that is an `Rectangle` and has a `getColor()` method? Now we can't even type check this expression.

Comment: How else would Java be designed? That's how OOP works - not all `Rectangle`s are also `ColoredRectangle`s.

Comment: The constructor for ```Rectangle``` is backwards, by the way: it updates its arguments from the member variables!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line, you are declaring that `sameObjectDifferentType` is of a type `Rectangle`

```
Rectangle sameObjectDifferentType = blueRectangle;
```

In more real world examples, this would allow you to have several different types, that you would want to treat in the same way. The classic example is `CurrentAccount`, `CheckingAccount`, `SavingsAccount` which all inherit from `Account`.

Suppose your banking application had code to lookup an account and find out the account holder. That code would just deal with the abstract `Account` types. It means that in the future when you introduce a `StudentAccount`, providing it inherits from `Account` you can use a `StudentAccount` in all the places you currently deal with `Account`s without changing code.

Suppose you had a `FilledRectangle` and `WireFrameRegtangle` in your example. You could have a `calculateArea(Rectangle rect)` method that would apply to all Rectangles.

However, one trade off you make for this power and flexibility is that you lose the ability to directly deal with properties of the subclass when you declare an object to be of a super class type, so

```
sameObjectDifferentType.getColor();  //Won't compile
```

However, Java does give you a way to get back to the subclass as you have noted by casting:

```
((ColoredRectangle) sameObjectDifferentType).getColor(); //Will compile
```

You as a developer know that `sameObjectDifferentType` is really a `ColoredRectangle` under the hood so you are safe to make this cast.However if you did

```
((FilledRectangle) sameObjectDifferentType).getFillPattern();
```

You would end up with a run time ClassCastException

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @yinder, If you're happy, please can you mark my answer as the accepted one by clicking on the tick next to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Rectangle sameObjectDifferentType = blueRectangle;
```

When you make a declaration like this, you are explicitly telling the compiler that it should be treated as a `Rectangle`.  While it may be a `ColoredRectangle` in this case, it would not take much for that guarantee to disappear.